# Instead of $.closest in Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jqlite

I want to implement this code in directive but in jQLite this doesn't work How should this be done?

```
 var thisCell = element.closest('.sampleclass');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement this functionality manually, for example:

```js
var thisCell = (function closest(e, className) {
  if (e[0].nodeName == "HTML") {
    return null;
  } else if (e.hasClass(className)) {
    return e;
  } else {
    return closest(e.parent(), className);
  }
})(element, "sampleclass");
```

Answer (score 4):

There's an experimental version of `.closest` in Firefox and Chrome as shown on [MDN - Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

With this in mind you could write something like this

```
var elm = document.querySelector('.myClass').closest();
```

or with `angular.element`

```
var elm = angular.element(document.querySelector('.myClass').closest());
```

Of course there's always exception to the rule (aka `IE`) and for them you could use the Polyfill which is also shown on [MDN - Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

```
if (window.Element && !Element.prototype.closest) {
    Element.prototype.closest = 
    function(s) {
        var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s),
            i,
            el = this;
        do {
            i = matches.length;
            while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== el) {};
        } while ((i < 0) && (el = el.parentElement)); 
        return el;
    };
}
```

I used this successfully to get the closest form of an element name by doing this line of code (it works in `IE` with the Polyfill:

```
var form document.querySelector('[name="elmName"]').closest("form");
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) states that:

> For lookups by tag name, try instead
>   angular.element(document).find(...) or $document.find(), or use the
>   standard DOM APIs, e.g. document.querySelectorAll().

Comment: This does not help if we need the closest parent that match something specific. i.e. you need the closest parent that has class `.item`. You want the one `.item` element that is the parent of the element you start with - not all `.item` elements in the page.